# Photons & Space

Tags: visible-light, photons, stars

If a star emits endless streams of light photons in all directions why is it that we have any darkness? Yes light can be absorbed by objects and transition into other particles but from its foundation and with the number of stars in the universe, why are we able to see gaps in space? We are essentially not being pelted by particle after particle right. Aren't we truly blanketed, constantly immersed, or better put drowning in an endless stream with no gaps in "space"?  Similar to bring submerged in water. There is no true emptiness in the space between us or any object. We are constantly absorbing. Constantly drowning.

I know that was more than one question and went on and on but these things are racking my novice brain at the moment.

Comment: More on [Olbers' paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=paradox+olber*).